# Using $watch in angularjs directive, why it works only with function as parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I researching angularjs application, and i don't understand why $watch in directive working as expected only with function in first parameter.

```
class PaginationController {
  constructor($scope) {
    "ngInject";
    this.quantity = null;
    this.$scope = $scope;

    $scope.$watch(() => this.quantity, function (newValue, OldValue) {
      console.log('new: ' + newValue);
      console.log('old: ' + OldValue);
    });
  }
}
```

If i just use this.quantity as first parameter $watch don't catch changing. But with function all work as i expected. What the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass variable to $watch as you will just pass variable value as for any JS function:

`a = 5; console.log(a);` is same to `console.log(5)`

And so `this.quantity = 1; $scope.$watch(this.quantity)` is same to `$scope.$watch(1)` and makes no sense.

What you can do is pass variable scope name:  `$scope.$watch('$ctrl.quantity', ...` (if $ctrl is ref of your controller)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS scope/rootScope Type API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: I would clarify the fact that it needs to be a string in the first parameter